# Why are constants not defined when using p5.js in instance mode?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm probably missing something very obvious here. I can use p5.js in global mode and use constants for textAlign with no problem, e.g. CENTER.

Here is global mode code where it works fine:

```
function setup() {
  var canvas = createCanvas(720, 400);  
  canvas.parent('main_canvas');
};

function draw() { 
  textSize(32);
  textAlign(CENTER);
  text("word", 50, 50);
};
```

However when I try using CENTER in instance mode I get:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: CENTER is not defined:
```

Here is instance mode code where it fails:

```
var s = function (p) {
  p.setup = function() {
    p.createCanvas(720, 400);
  };

  p.draw = function() {
    p.textSize(32);
    p.textAlign(CENTER);
    p.text("word", 50, 50);
  };
};
var myp5 = new p5(s,'main_canvas');
```

Any ideas on what I am missing here?

Comment: The point of instance mode is to keep everything related to p5.js out of the global namespace, even constants like `CENTER`, so this is by design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In global mode, all the P5.js functions **and variables** are added to the global namespace. In instance mode, all the P5.js functions **and variables** are added to the variable passed into the sketch function (in your case, your `p` variable).

To use the `CENTER` variable, you have to get at it through the `p` variable.

In other words, you need to do this:

```
p.textAlign(p.CENTER);
```

You'll also have to do this with other variables, like `mouseX` and `mouseY`.

Comment: The shame I feel right now knows no bounds. Thanks.

Comment: @e_r I think you've just described 75% of all programming! :p